# User data not posted when I click on register submit button in Angular 7

Tags: angular, laravel, api

Angular 7 and Laravel 5.8 are being used for an application. Laravel as the backend and Angular as the frontend. When I clicked on the submit button in Angular, nothing happens.

I tried to console it, but nothing was found. I tested it in POSTMAN and everything is okay.

My goals are:

1. when I click on Register Submit button, user data should be posted into the database
2. User must confirm the password

How do I achieve this?

I tried to check console, there is nothing there.

But when I tried to inspect, I got this in the network.

```
{success: false, message: "Invalid User Data", errorCode: 1,…}
data: {error: {password: ["The password confirmation does not match."]}}
error: {password: ["The password confirmation does not match."]}
errorCode: 1
message: "Invalid User Data"
success: false
```

[network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQrHd.png)

Laravel Backend

```
    public function returnResponse($success, $data, $errorCode = 0, $message = false) {
        $response = array();
        $response['success'] = $success;
        $response['message'] = isset($message) ? $message : '';
        if ($errorCode) {
            $response['errorCode'] = isset($errorCode) ? $errorCode : 0;
        }
        $response['data'] = $data;
        return response()->json($response, 200);
    }

    public function register(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'name' => 'required',
                    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
                    'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->returnResponse(false, ['error' => $validator->errors()], 1, 'Invalid User Data');
        }

        $input = $request->all();


        // code for check email exist or not
        if(isset($input['email'])){

            $alreadyExist = User::where(function ($query) use ($input) {
                    $query->where('email', '=', $input['email']);                           
                })->get();
        }

        if (count($alreadyExist->toArray()) > 0) {
            return $this->returnResponse(false, ['error' => 'Email Already Exist'], 1, 'User Data Already Exist');
        }


        // code for register user
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $input['name'];
        $user->email = $input['email'];
        $user->password = bcrypt($input['password']);
        $user->save();


        $success = array();
        $success['user_id'] = $user->id;
        $success['user']=$user;

        return $this->returnResponse(true, $success, 0, 'User registered successfully');
    }
```

route: api.php

```
    Route::post('register', 'ApiController@register');
```

Angular - register.service.ts

```
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      }

      register(user: any) {
       return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/register', user);
     }
```

register.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
    import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
    import { AuthenticationService } from '../../../../core/auth/services/authentication.service';
    import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
    import { from } from 'rxjs';

    declare var $;

   @Component({
      selector: 'app-register',
      templateUrl: './register.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
    })
    export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

      config: any;
      registerModel: any = {};
      name: string;

     constructor(
       private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
       private router: Router,
       private toastr: ToastrService,
     ) { }

      ngOnInit(
       ) {
       this.config = environment;
      }

      onRegister(registerform: any) {

       if (!registerform.valid) { // return false if form not valid
        return false;
      }

      this.authenticationService.register(this.registerModel)
       .pipe(first())
       .subscribe(
         response => {
          if (!response['success']) {
            this.toastr.error(response['message']);
            return false;
          }
          this.toastr.success(response['message']);
          registerform.reset();
          registerform.resetForm();
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        },
        error => {
          this.toastr.error(error);
        }
       );
      }

      }
```

register.component.html

```
    <form name="register" #registerform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onRegister(registerform);" novalidate>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control validate"
          [(ngModel)]="registerModel.name" #name="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : name.invalid && ((name.dirty || name.touched) || registerform.submitted)}" required  placeholder="Charles Okon" />
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
          <div *ngIf="name.invalid && ((name.dirty || name.touched) || registerform.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="name.errors?.required">Full Name is required.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control validate"
          [(ngModel)]="registerModel.email" #email="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : email.invalid && ((email.dirty || email.touched) || registerform.submitted)}" required  placeholder="example@email.com" />
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
          <div *ngIf="email.invalid && ((email.dirty || email.touched) || registerform.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="email.errors?.required">Email is required.</div>
              <div *ngIf="email.errors?.email">Please enter valid email.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="registerModel.password" #password="ngModel" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': password.invalid && ((password.dirty || password.touched) || registerform.submitted)}" required minlength="8" />
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
          <div *ngIf="password.invalid && ((password.dirty || password.touched) || registerform.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">Password is required.</div>
              <div *ngIf="password.errors.minlength">Please enter atleast 8 characters.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
      <div  *ngIf="error" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          Erro: {{ error }}
        </div>      
          <div class="form-group">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Register</button>          
        </div>
  </form>
```

When I clicked on register submit button, I expect it to post into user table but nothing happens

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Register</button>
```

Also, how do I confirm the password

Comment: Does the data passes from the frontend? Try to double check in the bottom part of headers section instead of network

Comment: How do I do that

Comment: Go to console -> network -> headers -> check the parameters, if its pass the all data, then its must be your backend problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `password confirmation` validation in your laravel backend code..

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'name' => 'required',
                    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
                    'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
```

But you did not have an field `password_confirmation` in your form. So you need add a one more field in your form or need to post an another field along with the signup data.

You can found more info at laravel validation [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation)

**Field Naming:**
The field under validation must have a matching field of foo_confirmation. For example, if the field under validation is password, a matching password_confirmation field must be present in the input.

Comment: Please how can I add the confirm password in frontend and backend

Comment: Just add a one more input field like password and use name of field `password_confirmation`

Comment: Is it Laravel backend or Angular frontend

Comment: Angular frontend

Comment: How. Please can you give a sample from my existing code

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an angular developer. You can hire a dev for this.

Comment: As per my understanding, it would be a copy of the password field with a minor change. `name` attribute